# The code was not function if SharedPreferences put in there

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

Hy guys i have a problem with my code, if i put SharedPreferences my code not function

i will explain with my following code

this is `menu.class`

```
public class menu extends Activity {

    Button f1, f2;
    ImageView f2lock;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.famouslevel);
        f1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.f1);      

        f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent level1 = new Intent ();
                level1.setClassName ("com.example.game", "com.example.game.levelone");
                startActivityForResult (level1, 0);              
            }             
        });     
    }   

    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent level1){
        super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, level1); 
        f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);      
        f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);

        switch (resultCode) {
            case 2:  f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
        }      

        f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent level2 = new Intent ();
                level2.setClassName ("com.example.game", "com.example.game.leveltwo");
                startActivityForResult (level2, 0);              
            }             
        });       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splashscreen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

if i use this code

```
        switch (resultCode) {
        case 2:  f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
        }
```

The code was running perfect, the f2 button in `menu.xml` is show up to `VISIBLE` and f2lock `GONE` but of course without `SharedPreferences` it won't save.

So if I change the code and put `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
switch (resultCode) {
    case 2:    
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);            
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); 
        editor.putBoolean("f2", levelTwoUnlocked);
        editor.commit();

        if(levelTwoUnlocked){
            f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
        }
        else {
            f2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            f2lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }      
}
```

The f2 button in `menu.xml` does not turn `VISIBLE`, it is still `GONE`. Yhe code does not function to make f2 button `VISIBLE` and f2lock `GONE`.

Can anyone help me with this code?

UPDATED

i have changed my code again

```
switch (resultCode) {
        case 2:    
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE); 
            //to make f2 VISIBLE and f2lock GONE
            boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("f2", true);      
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); 
            editor.putBoolean("f2", levelTwoUnlocked);
            editor.commit();

            if(levelTwoUnlocked){
                f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
            }
            else {
                f2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                f2lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }      
    }
```

still have the same problem, f2 won't setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't understand well what you're trying to do, but mistake is you never toggle your boolean `levelTwoUnlocked`. So don't mind how many times you enter in the `if`, the route will be always the same (I bet `levelTwoUnlocked=false` because is default Java `boolean` value):

```
if(levelTwoUnlocked){
    f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
    levelTwoUnlocked = false;
} else {
    f2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    f2lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    levelTwoUnlocked = true;
}
```

Comment: i have updated my code above in preference take a look Jordi

Comment: have you tried my answer? button shows and hides? which is the problem now?